# Disabling the default /?add-to-cart= animation on buttons in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to remove the default /?add-to-cart= animation buttons on the Shop Archive page. The default mode on a simple product shows a little spinner after clicking the button before showing a tick and providing a "View Cart" option link. (See here: https://snag.gy/ZreQid.jpg)

I would like the simple product Add to Cart button to redirect to the product page in the same way that the variable product does. (i.e. I want the client to view the product page after clicking the button, and I'll change "Add to Cart" label to "View Product" via the Booster for Woocommerce plugin).

So, I found this code on this [thread](https://www.pootlepress.com/2014/10/replace-add-to-cart-button-woocommerce-shop-page/):

```
/*STEP 1 - REMOVE ADD TO CART BUTTON ON PRODUCT ARCHIVE (SHOP) */

function remove_loop_button(){
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
}
add_action('init','remove_loop_button');

/*STEP 2 -ADD NEW BUTTON THAT LINKS TO PRODUCT PAGE FOR EACH PRODUCT */

add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','replace_add_to_cart');
function replace_add_to_cart() {
global $product;
$link = $product->get_permalink();
echo do_shortcode('<br>[button link="' . esc_attr($link) . '"]VIEW PRODUCT[/button]');
}
```

The first step works consistently well. The second step works some of the time. For example, on one site, Step 2 works a charm. On a second site (with the same theme, at the same host, etc. etc.), the button displays like this:

[button link="https://example.com/product/product-name/"]VIEW PRODUCT[/button]

i.e. the button doesn't show; this raw code is on display and it's not clickable. See here: https://snag.gy/FxEPWh.jpg

I hope I've explained it properly.

**Can anyone help to explain why the above code is not working consistently across different sites? Is there an easier way to do this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
add_filter('woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link','change_simple_shop_add_to_cart',10,2);
function change_simple_shop_add_to_cart( $html, $product ){
    if( $product->is_type('simple')) {

        $html = sprintf( '<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-product_id="%s"  class="button">%s</a>',
                esc_url( get_the_permalink() ),
                esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
                esc_html(  __( 'View Product', 'woocommerce' ) )
        );
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Logan. That worked well for most of my products and it's a much neater solution. However, I also have "simple" subscription products (Woocommerce Extension) but the solution didn't affect them. Would you know what I must add to the product type line for them?

Comment: If you know its product type then you can append the check with an && operator with  $product->is_type('simple'). For example for adding the check for variable products too you can try this ( $product->is_type('simple') &&  $product->is_type('variable') )

Comment: And according to your question it is the most suitable answer so please mark it as an answer. If you have any other queries you may ask here.